# How do I connect the edge connectors on the PCB to a breadboard?

Tags: connector, adapter

How do I connect the edge connectors on the PCB (shown in the below image) to a breadboard ? 
Are there any standard breakout boards or Adaptors available for this purpose ?

[Link](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/nordic/download_resource/38685/1/38514227) to the user guide of the PCB

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually have one of these, and it is meant to be just an evaluation board, so you aren't going to find any standard mounting setup.  I just used 30 AWG wire soldered from the board to my circuit.

These connections are meant to be breakouts that you can connect to a test board by soldering wires.  I think they are 0.1" spaced, but because of the way they are using only 1/2 of a hole, I would be careful not to put any mechanical force on those connections.  Big thick wires or connectors could fairly easily remove those pads if lateral forces were applied.

Answer (score 1):

Generally with devices like this, these are meant to be surface mounted onto your application board so there won't be a standard socket you can just pop this into.  Interesting that this has a USB connector because of that.

You can make it bread-board friendly by soldering a couple of sturdy wires or headers to the edge connectors.  If they are .1" spaced, then you are in luck because you can use a similar header which will make it look much cleaner.